# Maximal ideal in commutative Banach algebras. Why commutative?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, banach-algebras

I am having some trouble in understanding where is used the fact that the algebra is taken to be commutative in the following

> **Theorem.** Let $\mathcal A$ be a commutative Banach algebra (over $\mathbb C)$ with identity $e$ and let $x \in \mathcal A$. They are equivalent:
>
> 1. $x$ is not invertible in $\mathcal A$;
> 2. There existes a proper maximal ideal $\mathcal J \subset \mathcal A$, to which $x$ belongs.

The proof is as follows.

*Proof*.

NOT $1 \implies$ NOT $2$. Suppose $x$ is invertible. Then $\mathcal A x = \mathcal A$; hence, the only ideal containing $x$ is $\mathcal A$.

1 $\implies$ 2. If $x$ is not invertible, then $\mathcal A x$ is a proper ideal of $\mathcal A$, in fact, it does not contain $e$. Then Zorn's Lemma implies the existence of a proper maximal ideal which contains $\mathcal Ax$ and so $x$.
 $\square$

Now, how is made use of the fact that $\mathcal A$ is commutative, except for dropping qualifications *right/left* before the word "ideal"? Shouldn't "$x$ invertible" be enough to get $\mathcal A x = \mathcal A$?

**Remark.** The fact that $\mathcal A$ is Banach is obviously immaterial here; this theorem is taken from books on Banach algebras but it is known also in less specific contexts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the theorem could be slimmed down a lot.

In any ring $R$ with identity, $x\in R$ is a unit iff $xR=Rx=R$.

The $\implies$ direction is obvious, and the other direction is about as obvious.

Negating, we find that $x$ is not a unit iff $xR\neq R$ or $Rx\neq R$. In case $xR$ is proper, we can find a maximal right ideal containing it, and if $Rx$ is proper, we can find a maximal left ideal containing it.

Now, it is not true that $x$ is a unit iff $(x)=R$ for noncommutative rings in general. You can have $xy=1\neq yx$, in which case $(x)=R$, but $Rx\neq R$. But the $\implies $ direction still holds, of course.

Assuming commutativity just smooths out these pathologies.

Comment: That's quite similar to my picture. However, usually (as far as I know) an element in a Banach algebra is said to be invertible iff it has a two-sided inverse, differently from the usual definition in ring theory or in operator theory. This is in fact the reason why my doubt arose. Thank you.

Comment: @Federico the ring theoretic definition *is* that it has a two sided inverse. I'm not sure what gave you the idea anything was different.

Comment: Yeah, but it is sufficient $x$ has a left (or a right) inverse to prove the theorem (in the left/right ideal version), isn't?

Comment: @Federico You have to have *both* xR =Rx=R to conclude X is a unit. Just having one is insufficient

Comment: I know this. My point is that the equivalence still holds if we replace "$x$ is not invertible" with the more specific "$x$ has not left (/right) inverse" and the second statement with "There is a proper left (/right) maximal ideal containing $x$". In the case $A$ is commutative, we would recover the theorem as stated automatically. What changes is that  $A / J$ is no more a ring (in general) but only a module. This is a problem for further devolpments of B-algebras theory but not for our theorem, which, however, still holds even simply without commutativity assumption. Am I right?

Comment: @Federico I see, you had a slightly different formulation in mind. You could indeed say that X is not right invertible iff xR is contained in a maximal right ideal.